# Printing json object on an android textview

Tags: android, json

I have this json object as an output of a web service , I want to print each part_Name node on a separate android text view how to do that?

```
{
    "0": [],
    "1": {
        "Part_ID": "1",
        "Part_NAME": "part_name_one "
    },
    "2": {
        "Part_ID": "2",
        "Part_NAME": " part_name_two "
    },
    "3": {
        "Part_ID": "3",
        "Part_NAME": "part_name_three"
    },
```

I tried this code but I don't get an output in my textview

```
jobj = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://192.168.1.7:89/My_website/My_Webservice.php");

    try {
        JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(jobj.toString());

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("Services_Parts");


        for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);     

            String name = jsonObject.optString("Part_NAME").toString(); 

            data += "Node"+i+   "+ name +"  +name+ " \n ";              

            tv2.setText(name);  

                               }
```

Comment: dynamically create `textview` and add the `json` value to them.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: part_Name  count is always 3 or change dynamically

Comment: @Rustam please  I need a code to access json value

Comment: do you know JSON parsing? if don't know then check some tutorial try it and still having problem then ask.

Comment: I have edited the question and add my trial

Answer (score 1):

if possible then try to change the structure of your json to something like that

```
[
  {
    "Part_ID": "1",
    "Part_NAME": "part_name_one "
  },
  {
    "Part_ID": "2",
    "Part_NAME": " part_name_two "
  },
  {
    "Part_ID": "3",
    "Part_NAME": "part_name_three"
  }
]
```

> put each json object into an jsonarray .. as shown above

then parse each jsonobject and create the textview dynamically acc. to no. of jsonobject inside jsonarray

using the above ex. there are 3 jsonobject inside jsonarray
hence create 3 textview dynamically at the time of json parsing

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = <your json array>;

    for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);     
        String name = jsonObject.optString("Part_NAME").toString(); 

        addTextView(name); 
      }

     // add text to dynamically created textview code..
     public void addTextView(String text)
     {
         final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
         textView.setText(text);
         myLinearLayout.addView(textView);
     }
```

Comment: What is  myLinearLayout?

Comment: myLinearLayout in my case is the parent view at which these textview is been added...you can use any viewgroup like RelativeLayout or etc

Comment: Could I convert my jsonobject to jsonArray by code?

Comment: no you can't @JavaFan .... the json return by your webservice is need to be change for proper structural of json...although if dont want than...parse your json to your need